# XSLT unescaped result of sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm generating a plaintext file from an XML document. In the template, I have a simplified version of HTML that uses `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, `<pre>` and a few others.

In the source document, I have a node that looks like this:

```
<p>The respond category obeys the category laws, where respond is the identity and (/&gt;/) is composition:</p>
```

Near the bottom of my template, I have the following relevant rules:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine. I get the following output:

```
The respond category obeys the category laws, where respond is the identity and (/>/) is composition:
```

Now, here's where things go wrong. Based on [an answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856875/1405768), I discovered that I can get the output to line wrap with this change to the rule for `<p>` tags:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:variable name="aaa">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(concat(normalize-space($aaa),' '), '(.{0,60}) ', '  $1&#10;')"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This give me the following output:

```
The respond category obeys the category laws, where respond
is the identity and (/&gt;/) is composition:
```

It correctly wraps and left pads the output. However, the `>` symbol is now escaped. I tried adding `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to `sequence`, but `saxonb` errors with:

```
XTSE0090: Attribute @disable-output-escaping is not allowed on element <xsl:sequence>
```

Is there a way to avoid escaping the `>` symbol is this situation?

Comment: Do you have `xsl:output method="text"`?

Comment: That solved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `xsl:output method="text"`, as mentioned by Martin in the comments.