# How to insert a string after a certain number of string characters in XQuery?

Tags: string, insert, xquery

I want to insert a string (in this case, a linebreak, `\L`) after 25 characters into a string, but **only** at the next available whitespace, in order to avoid splitting words like below:

```
This is the example sente\L nce for you.
```

The correct output would be like this:

```
This is the example sentence\L for you.
```

The line break should occur approximately after 25 characters on each row, so a longer example would look like:

```
This is a longer example\L
for you; it actually contains\L
more than 50 characters.
```

What would be the simplest way to implement this in XQuery?

Comment: Should there be multiple line breaks inserted if the string is longer than 50 characters?

Comment: Yes, break at every 25 characters at whitespace. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution -- one needs just convert this to XQuery**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="my:my" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="my:splitAtWords(/*, 25, '\L&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:splitAtWords" as="xs:string?">
  <xsl:param name="pText" as="xs:string?"/>
  <xsl:param name="pMaxLen" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRep" as="xs:string"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "if($pText)
    then
     (for $line in replace($pText, concat('(^.{1,', $pMaxLen,'})\W.*'), '$1')
       return
          concat($line, $pRep,
                 my:splitAtWords(substring-after($pText,$line),$pMaxLen,$pRep))
      )
    else ()
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>This is a longer example for you; it actually contains more than 50 characters.</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
This is a longer example\L
 for you; it actually\L
 contains more than 50\L
 characters\L
.\L
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767452/xquery-word-wrap):

```
let $text := 'This is a longer example for you; it actually contains more than 50 characters.'
let $text-output := replace(concat($text,' '),'(.{0,25}) ','$1\\L')
return $text-output
```

Which returns the same as result as the XSLT from @dimitre-novatchev above:

```
This is a longer example\L
for you; it actually\L
contains more than 50\L
characters.\L
```