# String wrap using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to wrap a string using xquery, something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767452/xquery-word-wrap) but it wraps every x any characters, it doesn't have to be a space.
For example

string:
123456789

result:
123
456
789

Comment: Just use a different regex: `replace('123456789','(.{3})','$1&#xA;')`